# Failed to launch the debugger Python

Tags: python, visual-studio, debugging

I've installed the Python plugin in Visual Studio 2019 (Python 3.7), but when I launch the debugger, I get the error in the picture below:

[image: error]

What is the problem, and how do I solve it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I think its better to uninstall and install again that environment, or install another version of python environment.